# Django rest framework working with multiple apps

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

My aim is to authorize browsable API(first app) using the JWT token generated(second app).
I have two apps created,
1. API - has all the data
2. Authentication - generate JWT tokens after validating the user.

Now, when I try to access the API after generating the token it says,
Authentication credentials were not provided.

[Trying to access the API (passing the bearer whatevertoken)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pSS3.png)

I mean, is there a way to authenticate the Browsable API using JWT token? Instead of creating a user session.

Comment: Will update the questions with some screenshots soon.

Comment: Your `Bearer whatevertoken` or `Basic whatevertoken` has to be in headers when you're connecting.

Comment: @dmitryro Thanks.
Well I already tried that, it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing Authorization header as,

> "Authorization: JWT **token**"

authenticates the user.

But, limits me to browse the API in a browser. Is there any way we can implement Browsable API using JWT authentication?

**UPDATE**

A thorough reading on

1. [Authentication classes](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)
2. [Permission classes](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)
3. [Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/)

Helped in understanding the core concepts and apply appropriate solutions.